# Cannot run Django development server

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'm new to Django and have gone through the recommended installation (set up for GeoDjango) and am now going through the general django tutorial to get an idea of how it works.

IN the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/, it tells you to try and run the django development server with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but when I do I get an error

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x04E20300>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

If anyone could shed any light on why this might be happening that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What is your DATABASES setting?

Comment: Realised the problem! Your comment reminded me that I'd changed the settings for the GeoDjango tutorial before switching to the Django one so I've set them to their original values and it's working now